# How can I define an empty array in a Perl construtor?

Tags: perl, arrays, oop

I am just beginner with Perl, so if it sounds stupid - sorry for that :)

My problem is - I am trying to write a class, which has an empty array, defined in constructor of a class. So I am doing this like this:

```
package MyClass;

use strict;

sub new {
    my ($C) = @_;
    my $self = {
        items => ()
    };
    bless $self, ref $C || $C;
}

sub get {
    return $_[0]->{items};
}

1;
```

Later I am testing my class with simple script:

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use MyClass;

my $o = MyClass->new();
my @items = $o->get();

print "length = ", scalar(@items), "\n", Dumper(@items);
```

And while running the script I get following:

```
$ perl my_test.pl 
length = 1
$VAR1 = undef;
```

Why am I doing wrong what causes that I get my `items` array filled with `undef`?

Maybe someone could show me example how the class would need to be defined so I would not get any default values in my array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The anonymous array reference constructor is `[]` not `()` which is used to group statements into lists.  The `()` in this case flattens to an empty list and perl sees `my $self = {  item => };`.  If you were running with `use warnings;` you would have gotten a message about that.

Also, in your `get` subroutine you will probably want to dereference your field to return the list instead of a reference to the array:

```
sub get {
    return @{ $_[0]->{items} };
}
```